# 16.04, kernel 4.15.0-33, Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f1 - no sound

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound

When using kernel 4.15.0-33, then I have no sound on my computer
Sound is working if I start with kernel 4.4.0-134

Here are output showing that the Soundcard is not recognized by 4.15.0-33

Using "old" kernel 4.4.0-134

`lspci -v`

> 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset
>   Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)  Subsystem: Gigabyte
>   Technology Co., Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High
>   Definition Audio Controller   Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency
>   0, IRQ 5  Memory at fbff8000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
>     Capabilities:

`aplay -l`

> device_list:270: no soundcards found...

Using "new" kernel 4.15.0-33
`lspci -v`

> 01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 10f1 (rev a1)
>     Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device 6161  Flags: bus master, fast
>   devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17     Memory at faffc000 (32-bit,
>   non-prefetchable) [size=16K]  Capabilities:    Kernel
>   driver in use: snd_hda_intel  Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

`aplay -l`

> The sound card is recognized (forgot to copy the exact output)

Anyone who could could fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I installed 18.04.1 and the sound is working with 4.15 kernel